# Bower.io. Installing dependencies

Tags: javascript, dependencies, bower

I have the latest version (as of this writing) 1.3.12. I am trying to install dependencies:

```
bower install
```

During installation I get an error:

```
bower ENORESTARGET  No tag found that was able to satisfy ~2.0.3

Additional error details:
No versions found in git://github.com/theshock/atomjs.git
```

and installation aborted.

How to resolve this problem?
Thank

Comment: Are you sure it can be installed with Bower? Because theshock/atomjs repo doesn't have any release tags. How do you know you need 2.0.3?

Comment: I do not need it and I did not point it clearly in their addiction.

Comment: It'll help if you update your question with contents of your `bower.json`. Clearly somebody is depending on theshock/atomjs ~2.0.3. The `bower.json` should tell who.

Answer (score 1):

For the people who are still getting this problem on Windows even though they are sure that the packages have correct versions, problem might be caused by the console emulator.

> As I found out [here](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/852#issuecomment-141724402) from the comment posted by **m0n1ker**, the problem was caused by **ConEmu** console emulator. He says:
>
> > Ok, I did some debugging and for those that are having issues with ConEmu, the issue is not with bower. Where bower makes the call value = cmd('git', ['ls-remote', '--tags', '--heads', source]).spread(function (stdout) { in GitRemoteResolver.js the stdout variable is getting truncated to 4096 characters. This is a bug in the ConEmuHk DLL.

I am using **cmder** console emulator and thanks to [grafikkaos](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/852#issuecomment-145169743) I was able to solve the problem by disabling `Inject ConEmuHk` under `Settings -> Features -> In-console options`. After doing that I can now install/update bower packages without any problem.